# What determine whether an object will absorb or transmit light?

Tags: visible-light

If the energy of the light falling is not equal to the difference between any two orbitals of the atom then the electron absorb the light but re-emit it either through the object or reflect it backwards. Bit what determines that the re-emitted light would be transmitted or reflected?